# Change UIView / UIViewController on device orientation change

Tags: ios, device-orientation, swift5

For those that use the iOS Calendar a lot, you know that when you change the orientation of the phone, another view is presented. I am not sure oof this is changing to a subview, a new UIViewController, size classes or some programatic voodoo that Apple has spun.

I can do some of the features with a subview that changes constrains on orientation change, but that is about it. It looks crude and I thought there might be a better way to imitate the Calendar App.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely uses [`UISplitViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller) to achieve this effect. This lets you display two child view controllers side by side.

You can change its [`preferredDisplayMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller/1623170-preferreddisplaymode) property to show or hide secondary (or primary) view controller or set it to `.automatic` to let it choose the most appropriate layout for the available space.

Comment: I can appreciate that solution, but what I am trying to create is that the secondary view controller will only be seen when the phone is rotated from Portrait to Landscape. Then it will fill the entire screen. Just like the calendar app. If you rotate the pone you get an entirely different view. (granted I am seeing trees not the forest right now.so feel free to jab me to get me to see. ;) )

Comment: @JamieD This is exactly what UISplitViewController is used for

Comment: Last time I used UISplitViewController it was a different beast apparently. Is there an example of using UISplitViewController on a phone that only appears when the phone orientation changes? I have searched Google and not found any.

Comment: @JamieD Quote from my answer: "You can change its `preferredDisplayMode` property to show or hide secondary (or primary) view controller or set it to `.automatic` to let it **choose the most appropriate layout for the available space.**" It should detect orientation change and change the display mode automatically. You can also take it under manual control, detect orientation changes yourself, and change the preferredDisplayMode to your liking.